# iTerm2 vim cannot map alt key

Tags: macos, vim, osx-lion, key-binding, iterm2

I'm having trouble trying to map the alt-key bindings on vim in iTerm2. I want to map shortcuts for switching between buffers like this:

```
map <A-Right> <C-w>l
map <A-Left> <C-w>h
map <A-Down> <C-w>j
map <A-Up> <C-w>k
```

But I can't get it to work. I've tried everything, setting the option key as "Normal", "Meta" and "+Esc" in the profile settings. I've tried `<M-Right>` and `<T-Right>` but those don't work either. There are posts on superuser and stackoverflow but they use the old version of iTerm2 (v0.x).

The only things I've managed to get working are `<T-up>` and `<T-down>`, or when I just use Macvim.

I'm using iTerm2  v1.0.0.20120203, and Mac OS X 10.7.5 on a Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 7):

Since Mac OS X uses the option key to insert characters, regular `<A-[key]>` mappings won't work. Thus `:h i_CTRL-V` becomes your friend. Your right arrow mapping, for example, can be typed like this:

`map`<kbd>control</kbd><kbd>V</kbd><kbd>option</kbd><kbd>→</kbd>`<C-w>l`

This will result in what looks like:

```
map ^[f <C-w>l
```

Note, however, that you can't copy and paste the above, as `^[` is one character in vim, but is here represented with two characters. Most vim users would suggest, however, that you not use the arrow keys for this (or anything). I use `map <C-l> <C-w>l` (and likewise for h, j, k) instead, as it keeps my hands on the keyboard.

Answer (score 1):

See [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8224269/546861) on a similar question. My advice is to use `:h mapleader`.